# How to use SUM when foreign key and primary key matched in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sum

Currently I have 2 tables which is document and item table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `document` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `dateDoc` datetime NOT NULL,
  `numDoc` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `idCategory` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subject` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'A',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=155 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `item` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idDoc` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `numItem` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `amount` decimal(14,4) NOT NULL,
  `idTax` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rateTax` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amtTax` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=244 ;
```

How to sum up the amount and amtTax in Table 'item' if document(id) = item (idDoc).

For example :

(document table)

Document id = 1;

(item table)

```
id = 1;
idDoc = 1;
amount = 50.00;
amtTax = 10.00;


id = 2;
idDoc = 1;
amount = 30.00;
amtTax = 6.60;
```

**I suppose to get RM96.60.**

How to sum up the amount and amtTax in mysql as a new column named (Total) if idDoc match with document table's id?
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to select all documents with their sums of amounts and amt taxes, use a join with group by over the documents:

```
SELECT SUM(item.amount) + SUM(item.amtTax) AS Total
FROM document
LEFT JOIN item
    ON document.id = item.idDoc
```

If you want to select just a single document (e.g. the one with id 1), you don't need to use group by, just add where clause:

```
SELECT document.*, sum(item.amount) + sum(item.amtTax) as Total
FROM document LEFT JOIN item ON document.id = item.idDoc
WHERE document.id = 1
```

Comment: Hi. What if I want to list all the items based on the document id?

Comment: MySQL extends the use of GROUP BY so that you can use nonaggregated columns or calculations in the SELECT list that do not appear in the GROUP BY clause. Moreover as we are gouping over a primary key, there won't be any ambiguity.

Comment: @martin.macko.47 Simply because it allows this does not mean we should use it.  Furthermore, newer versions of MySQL may not allow it at all.  But other than this your queries look correct.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen your edit is wrong, now you will get just the `id` and the `total`. I understood the question was to get existing columns and "a new column named Total". Therefore then you need to group over *all* document columns or use a subquery. On the other side, if you wanted just the `id`, the join was not nessesary then.